# How can I make an auto-zero (re-displace) a graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

That is, if my first data point is (1000, 50), how would I make it on the very bottom left (origin point of graph), and shift all corresponding data? I'm working with pandas and matplotlib, and I have the following code for processing my current data (just columns in excel):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

fig = Figure(figsize=(12, 10), dpi=100)
fig.add_subplot(111).scatter(df['A'], df['B'], s=0.1)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.parent)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

The data.csv has two columns which I am graphing against each other, but I want to manipulate the graph so that the origin point of the graph is the first point in the data.

I tried the following but the graph stays the same:

```
    fig = Figure(figsize=(12, 10), dpi=100)
    fig.add_subplot(111).scatter(df['Load On Sample'], df['Displacement Into Surface'], s=0.1)
    fig.add_axes(xlim=(df['Load On Sample'][0], None))
    fig.add_axes(ylim=(df['Displacement Into Surface'][0], None))
```

Comment: Do you want to shift all data so that the first data point is (0, 0)? Or do you simply want to have the bottom-left corner of the plot line up with your first data point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the axes limits to coincide with your first point, you can set them like so:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

fig = Figure(figsize=(12, 10), dpi=100)
fig.add_subplot(111).scatter(df['A'], df['B'], s=0.1)
# assign the generated axes to a variable
ax = fig.gca()
# customize appearance of the axes
# xlim, ylim correspond to horizontal and vertical axes extents, respectively
# you pass (lower_bound, upper_bound), with `None` being the default
ax.set(xlim=(df['A'][0], None), ylim=(df['B'][0], None))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.parent)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: It says that my "Path collection" object has no property 'xlim' or 'ylim'.

Comment: I added my changed code into my question, but the graph appears the same.

Comment: @ephemeralhappiness I have updated my answer using the `Figure.gca()` method to grab the existing axis belonging to the figure.